# Grid pagination not working when use group clause in collection

Tags: magento, collections, grid, magento-1.9

I m working on product grid but its pagination or product count not working(as it display wrong count).
as my block _preparecollection function is as below.i have added category filter code in collection so i have to use group clause to prevent error for same id already exist.

```
 protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id')
            ->joinField('category_id',
                'catalog/category_product',
                'category_id',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                null,
                'left');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array(4,10)))
            ->distinct(true);
            $collection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');


        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_CatalogInventory')) {
            $collection->joinField('qty',
                'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                'qty',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left');
        }
        $collection->joinField('position',
                'catalog/category_product',
                'position',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                null,
                'left');
        $collection->joinField('websites',
            'catalog/product_website',
            'website_id',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            null,
            'left');
        if ($store->getId()) {
            //$collection->setStoreId($store->getId());
            $adminStore = Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID;
            $collection->addStoreFilter($store);
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'name',
                'catalog_product/name',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $adminStore
            );

            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'custom_name',
                'catalog_product/name',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'status',
                'catalog_product/status',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'visibility',
                'catalog_product/visibility',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'price',
                'catalog_product/price',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'left',
                $store->getId()
            );
        }
        else {
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
            $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
            $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
        }

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        parent::_prepareCollection();
        $this->getCollection()->addWebsiteNamesToResult();
        return $this;
    }
```

I had googled and tried this by adding to `lib/varian/data/collection/db.php` (without any luck)

```
 public function getSelectCountSql()
{
     $this->_renderFilters();

        $countSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);

        if(count($this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP)) > 0) {
            $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
            $countSelect->distinct(true);
            $group = $this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
            $countSelect->columns("COUNT(DISTINCT ".implode(", ", $group).")");
        } else {
            $countSelect->columns('COUNT(*)');
        }
        return $countSelect;
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Copy Db.php file from magento / lib / Varien / Data / Collection / Db.php

Paste it to your local directory so the resultant folder structure would look like this:

**magento / app / code / local / Varien / Data / Collection / Db.php**

Now open this file to edit and replace getSelectCountSql function with below one,

```
public function getSelectCountSql()
{
    $this->_renderFilters();

    $countSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);

    if(count($this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP)) > 0) {
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
        $countSelect->distinct(true);
        $group = $this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
        $countSelect->columns("COUNT(DISTINCT ".implode(", ", $group).")");
    } else {
        $countSelect->columns('COUNT(*)');
    }
    return $countSelect;
}
```

Comment: I have change it to core first so check if it work then i will override but it did'nt work in core bro.I have also mentioned that i used above code but still not working.